# change language in android application

Tags: android

I want to make my application  a multi language application. If I press a button, the language of application will change. I added multi languages String files in my values folder, but how could I update the language og the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multi-launguages string files will be used only based on `configuration`.So you need to update it programmatically.

**Example snippet:**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");//fr is the code for french language
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

after running above code,you may call `onCreate` again, just to update the current screen

Comment: is there will an interrution when language will  change or it will change so fast even user dosnt saw it

Comment: @Sultan it depends upon the performance and capability of device. generally, it will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android).
It talks about "changing the language setting programatically". 
Wish it helps.

Comment: just to help you in improving,you should not post `link only answers`.it is discouraged.keep a habit to add some description or code to guide others.